# Hackerearth Simple Function - Follow-up

Tags: c#, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

[Problem statement](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/simple-function/)

> Let us first describe a `SimpleFunction`:
>
> ```
> SimpleFunction( string A,string B ){ 
>
>    int answer = 0;    
>    for( int dig = 1; dig <= 9; dig++ ){    
>         if(string A contains digit dig and string B contains digit dig){    
>             answer = answer * 10 + dig;    
>    }    
>    return answer;
> }
> ```
>
> So basically this function receives two strings as an input and
>   returns a value.
>
> **Akshara** recently gained interest in coding and she came across this interesting question. She had 2 baskets. Each basket contained a
>   few strings. She wanted to find out what is the **probability** of
>   picking up  2 strings, 1st string from the first basket and the 2nd
>   string from the second basket, such that the value returned from the
>   Simple function would be an even value.
>
> Since she is not that good at Mathematics, she turns to you for help.
>   Please help her in solving this problem!
>
> **Input**: The first line contains an integer \$T\$ denoting the number of test cases. The first line of each test case contains 2
>   integers \$N1\$ and \$N2\$ denoting the size of first basket and
>   second basket respectively. This is followed up by \$(N1 + N2)\$
>   lines. Each line contains a string. The first \$N1\$ string correspond
>   to the first basket while the remaining to the second basket.
>
> **Output:**
>
> For each test case output the required probability correct up to 3
>   decimal places.
>
> **Constraints:**
>
> - \$1 \le T \le 10\$
> - \$1 \le N1, N2 \le 1000\$
> - \$1 \le \text{Length of String} \le 1000\$
>
> Every String is composed of digits from `[1 - 9]`
>
> **Sample input**
>
> ```
> 1
> 2 2
> 234526
> 8345
> 333564
> 98847675
> ```
>
> **Sample output**
>
> ```
> 0.750
> ```
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The output of all the combination will be:
>
> ```
> Simple(234526,333564) = 3456
> Simple(8345,333564) = 345
> Simple(8345,98847675) = 458
> Simple(234526,98847675) = 456
> ```
>
> Since 3 of them are even, probability is \$\frac{3}{4}\$.
>
> Time Limit: 1.0 sec(s) for each input file.
>
> Memory Limit: 256 MB

My introduction of the algorithm:

I asked the code review for my previous solution [HackerEarth - SimpleFunction](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/151436/hackerearth-simplefunction), and then the feedback is "The code is hard to follow". Afterwards, I spent a few hours to work on the algorithm again, rewrite and passed all test code, and code is much simple. Here is the [code link](https://gist.github.com/jianminchen/b223aee89fd0f9753fe730735d0ddb29).

I learned a few lessons through the practice. Most of important is to use counting sort to find two integers' (\$1 <= N <= 1000\$) last digit, avoid using time-consuming string manipulation. And also, avoid complicated code, jagged array with 3 dimension seems to be hard to follow in my previous solution. Most of important is that the time complexity is very easy to compute \$O(N1*N2)\$, \$N1, N2\$ are two integers in two baskets, both are less than \$1000\$.  The algorithm uses less memory, time is almost same as the previous one.

**The current algorithm's result on hackerearth**

[image]

**The previous algorithm's result on hackerearth.com**

[image]

I like to ask review again for the same algorithm.

```cs
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Diagnostics;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

   namespace SimpleFunction
   {
      /*
       * Hackerearth.com simple function
       * https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/simple-function/
       */
     class Program
     {
       /*
        * Use an integer array to express an integer from 1 to 1000, array size is 10. 
        * Store digit i from 1 to 9 if there is any digit i in the integer. 
        * 
        * For example, a number from 1 to 1000, 246 will be represented as int[]{0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0}.
        * 
        * Design of hashed integer: 
        * 1. Number of same digits in the integer will not be saved, the information will be losted, for example, 
        * integers 1, 11, 111 will be saved to same array {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
        * 
        * 2. And also the order does not matter, 123, 213, 321 will be hashed to same array {0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}
        */
       internal class HashedInteger
       {
          private static int SIZE = 10; 
          public int[] values; 

          public HashedInteger()
          {
            values = new int[SIZE]; 
          }

          /*
           * @number - a string representing an integer from 1 to 1000, 
           */
          public static HashedInteger Convert(string number)
          {                
            HashedInteger digits = new HashedInteger();
            foreach (char c in number)
            {
                digits.values[ c- '0'] = 1;
            }

            return digits;
          }

          public static HashedInteger[] ConvertAll(string[] numbers)
          {
            if (numbers == null || numbers.Length == 0)
                return new HashedInteger[] { };

            int length = numbers.Length;
            IList<HashedInteger> output = new List<HashedInteger>();
            foreach (string number in numbers)
            {
                output.Add(HashedInteger.Convert(number));
            }

            return output.ToArray();
          }      

          /*              
           * Find largest digit in two numbers expressed in Digits
           * 
           * return: last digit
           */
          public static int GetLastDigit(HashedInteger firstOne, HashedInteger secondOne)
          {
            int lastDigit = 0;

            for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (firstOne.values[i] == 1 && secondOne.values[i] == 1)
                {
                    lastDigit = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return lastDigit;
          }
       }        

       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
         ProcessInputs();

         // RunSampleTestCase(); 
       }

       private static int RunSampleTestCase2()
       {
         return 0;
       }

       /*
        * Sample test case in problem description
        */
       private static void RunSampleTestCase()
       {
        int[] baskets = new int[] { 2, 2 };

        int numberInFirstBasket = baskets[0];
        int numberInSecondBaseket = baskets[1];

        string[] numbersInFirst = new string[] { "234526", "8345" };
        string[] numbersInSecond = new string[] { "333564", "98847675" };

        int count = CalculateSumOfEvenNumbers(numbersInFirst, numbersInSecond);
        int totalCount = CalculateTotalCount(numbersInFirst, numbersInSecond);

        double prob = count * 1.0 / totalCount;
        Debug.Assert((prob.ToString("#.000").CompareTo("0.750")) == 0);
      }

      /*
       * return value: probablity of even numbers compared to total pairs
       */
      private static void ProcessInputs()
      {
        int queries = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int no = 0; no < queries; no++)
        {
            int[] baskets = Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Split(' '), int.Parse);

            int numberInFirstBasket   = baskets[0];
            int numberInSecondBaseket = baskets[1];

            string[] numbersInFirst = new string[numberInFirstBasket];
            string[] numbersInSecond = new string[numberInSecondBaseket];

            for (int i = 0; i < numberInFirstBasket; i++)
                numbersInFirst[i] = Console.ReadLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < numberInSecondBaseket; i++)
                numbersInSecond[i] = Console.ReadLine();

            int count = CalculateSumOfEvenNumbers(numbersInFirst, numbersInSecond);

            int totalCount = CalculateTotalCount(numbersInFirst, numbersInSecond);

            double prob = count * 1.0 / totalCount;
            Console.WriteLine(prob.ToString("N3"));
        }
      }

     /*
      * 
      * Choose any number from each basket, compare two numbers to find largest digit in both numbers. 
      * If the largest digit is the even number, then add to the sum. Ruturn the value of sum of largest digit
      * of a pair number from two baskets. 
      */
      private static int CalculateSumOfEvenNumbers(string[] numbersA, string[] numbersB)
      {
        int count = 0;

        HashedInteger[] shortNumbers1 = HashedInteger.ConvertAll(numbersA);
        HashedInteger[] shortNumbers2 = HashedInteger.ConvertAll(numbersB);

        foreach (HashedInteger firstOne in shortNumbers1)
        {
            foreach (HashedInteger secondOne in shortNumbers2)
            {                    
                int lastDigit = HashedInteger.GetLastDigit(firstOne, secondOne);

                if (lastDigit % 2 == 0)
                    count++;
            }
        }

        return count;
      }                              

      private static int CalculateTotalCount(string[] numbersInFirst, string[] numbersInSecond)
      {
        return numbersInFirst.Length * numbersInSecond.Length;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding regarding the constraints: not the single number that each _digit string_ could be interpreted as is limited by `1≤N1,N2≤1000`. The _count_ of digit strings in _basket1_ is `N1` (1, at least, and 1000, at most), the same limits apply to `N2`, the count of digit strings in _basket2_. (That and the fact that you keep all strings before turning them into sets may be responsible for the memory usage of `Input #1`.)

Comment: @greybeard, you are correct. I read problem statement again, the string length is in range of [1,1000]. Sample test case string in basket 1 are 234526 and 8345, both are more than 3 digits. Good catch!

Comment: @gretbeard, the class HashedInteger's description has to be updated, ""Use an integer array to express an integer from 1 to 1000, array size is 10. Store digit i from 1 to 9 if there is any digit i in the integer.", should be written "Use an integer array to express a string with length from 1 to 1000 containing digits from 1 to 9, and the integer array size is 10. Store digit i from 1 to 9 if there is any digit i in the string."

Comment: `string with length from 1 to 1000` sure closely follows the wording from the original problem statement. I'd avoid `Use [X] to express [Y]` where X cannot be reconstructed from Y. `Store digit i from 1 to 9` isn't quite what is happening - (record, denote,) _represent absence of digit `i` with a zero at index `i`, its presence with a non-zero value_ (one/1?)? See my answer to the first iteration of your question for a representation of each basket using no more than 512 integers for _any_ number of _digit strings_ (and time complexity O(1) _+O(n) input_: "online algorithm").